# Unable to set python environments with old interpreters

Tags: bash, installation, python, packages, virtualenv

I have installed `virtualenvwrapper` on Arch Linux, as well as the [AUR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Python#Old_versions) repository `python38` so I can set an environment and work with TensorFlow. I have set up `.bashrc` as usually recommended on the [docs](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/4.8.4/install.html) and I was good to go:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/home/myuser/.local/bin"

# Virtualenv custom folder
export WORKON_HOME=/home/myuser/development/venvs

# Remaining configurations
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
source /usr/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

When calling `mkvirtualenv test` and `workon`, the venv is correctly built and listed, and it can be accessed normally.

However, since I want to be able to install TensorFlow, I change the `PYTHON` variable:

```
export VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.8
```

But now when I restart the shell and try to create a virtual environment, an error occurs due to a missing package.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 16, in <module>
    from stevedore import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stevedore/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .extension import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3.8 and that PATH is
set properly.
created virtual environment CPython3.9.1.final.0-64 in 227ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/myuser/development/venvs/testing, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/myuser/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==21.0.1, setuptools==52.0.0, wheel==0.36.2
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator,XonshActivator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper/hook_loader.py", line 16, in <module>
    from stevedore import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stevedore/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from .extension import ExtensionManager
  File "/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/stevedore/extension.py", line 17, in <module>
    import pkg_resources
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pkg_resources'
```

I find this strange because there is a `virtualenvwrapper` folder inside `/home/myuser/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages` (while ironically there **is not** one in `python3.9/site-packages`) and I am unable to install it manually:

```
$ python3.8 -m pip install --user pkg_resources
/usr/bin/python3.8: No module named pip
```

What is going on here? Honestly this is the third or fourth time I'm trying to work with venvs, but I can't find a single source reliably explaining how I am supposed to deal with them and every single time there has been some major setback which simply makes me give up. =(

---

**EDIT:** running `mkvirtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.8 new_venv` has actually worked, but as I'm only planning to use venvs to deal with older versions, I'd like to set it up directly as a variable.